# What does the root `CompoundStm` for the following source `stm1;stm2;stm3` have 2 child statements

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

I'm reading [Modern Compiler Implementation in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052182060X) and the following simple source program code is shown:

```
a := 5+3; b := (print(a, a-1), 10*a); print(b)
```

The tree representation of the program looks like this:

```
               CompoundStm
             /            \
            /              \
       a := 5+3            b := (print(a, a-1), 10*a); print(b)
       AssignStm           CompoundStm
      /         \         /          \
     /           \       /            \
    a           OpExp  AssignStm      PrintStm
                       /      \
                      b       EsecExp
```

But I expected it to be like this:

```
                    CompoundStm
             /             |       \
            /              |        \
       a := 5+3  b := (pr...), 10*a) print(b)
       AssignStm       AssignStm     PrintStm  
      /         \         /   \
     /           \       /     \
    a           OpExp  b       EsecExp
```

What does the first `CompoundStm` have 2 children instead of 3? Is it because `CompoundStm` can only have 2 children?

Comment: It's basically treating the `;` as an infix operator with two operands.

Comment: @sepp2k, yeah, thanks, I'm also wondering _why_ it does so. Is it maybe because `CompoundStm` can only have 2 children? Like the tree has to be binary

Comment: Abstract syntax trees are typically implemented as binary trees.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, that's what I thought, thanks for taking the time to confirm that

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I wouldn't say that. For example I've never seen if-then-else represented as anything other than a node with three children. And in languages where a compound-statement has the form `'{' statement* '}'` it's perfectly common to represent it as a node holding a list of statements (i.e. a node with variably many children). It's just that this language seems to use the syntax `compound-statement ::= statement ';' statement`, so a node with two children is the natural representation.

Comment: As for why the language is defined that way: I haven't read the book in question, but possibly the language is inspired by ML (which I think is  also the language that the original version of the book is written for), where `;` is also defined as a binary operator.

Comment: @sepp2k, I see, thanks a lot for your insights